# Rails 4 - Devise_scope, root not working for multiple type of users (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sti

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect to root for different devise_scope user models. Able to sign in/out in each scope w/o problem, but root always working only as first one(company).
I tried to change **device_scope** to **as** or **scope** still no luck

```
/routes.rb

authenticated :user do

devise_scope :company do
 root :to => 'company/main#account', :as => :company_root
get 'main/account', :to => 'company/main#account', :as => :company_main_account
end

devise_scope :employee do
 root :to => 'employee/main#account', :as => :employee_root
 get 'employee/main/account', :to => 'employee/main#account', :as => :employee_main_account
end

devise_scope :professional do
 root :to => 'professional/main#account', :as => :professional_root
 get 'professional/main/account', :to => 'professional/main#account', :as => :professional_main_account
end
end

unauthenticated do
root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

tried this approach as well no luck as well, root not working for all scopes

```
root :to => 'company/main#account', :constraints => lambda { |request|request.env['warden'].user.class.name == 'Company' }, :as => "company_root"
root :to => 'employee/main#account', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.class.name == 'Employee' }, :as => "employee_root"
```

Feeling like I tried all possible ways already, please any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with one root to, `root :to => 'welcome#index'`

And in your `welcome` controller, handle it

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
      if user.class.name == "Company"
        redirect_to company_root_path(current_user)
      elsif user.class.name == "Employee"
        redirect_to employee_root_path(current_user)
      else
        redirect_to professional_root_path(current_user)
      end
  end
end
```

There may be some better solutions, but I guess you can start of with this one.

Comment: Thanks for solution, it's working as expected. 
Updated user to 'current_user', cause 'user' was giving error. I have one question, my url for employee root has number 23 not sure what is it, http://0.0.0.0:3000/employee/main%23account. Do you know how to hide  this number?

Comment: It maybe the id of the user who is signed in. You may want to look into `friendly_id` gem

Comment: I found what was it. I used employee/main#account instead of employee/main/account. Now looks perfect. Thanks for help!